# Finding Volume Integration Method

Tags: integration, volume

One of the applications of integration is to find volume of solids. But How do i understand to use which method to be used ? For example Cross section, washer, shell etc

Comment: Essentially any method can be used, but some methods are *easier* to use depending on the geometry and symmetry of the solid. For example if the solid is radially symmetric you would want to take advantage of methods that revolve infinitesimal segments about the axis of symmetry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i tried to solve one question with both 2 method and the answer was the same.